# JSF el - integrate with mvel

Tags: jsf-2, mvel

is it possible to use MVEL (http://mvel.codehaus.org/Home) with JSF? I cannot find a class that is an "ExpressionFactory" in the code? MVEL seems to use the static MVEL class, so I don't know what to write in my web.xml for the "org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY" context param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, because MVEL is not the standard EL that comes from JSP and has been developed in JSR-245 and JSR-341. For example take a look at [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/). It is an implementation of the specification defined in JSR-245 (jcp.org). It could be feasible to create a wrapper between MVEL and UEL, but that could be pointless, because UEL is flexible enough. My suggestion is use JUEL and MyFaces Core with EL expression cache enabled. The implementation bundled in Tomcat is quite ok, it had some issues long time ago but those ones has been fixed and it is stable.

Comment: Too bad, MVEL seemed to be very fast. I did not see that much increase in performance from JUEL. I will try the cache, I was a bit worried that some stuff would stop working